# How to check on the server that the client is authenticated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**SITUATION:**

Currently, I pass the UID through the url to the server.

I then use the UID to check in the database if that UID exists:

---

**CODE:**

```
router.get("/profile/:uid", function(req, res, next){

var uid = req.params.uid;

var userRef = admin.database().ref("users/"+uid);

userRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
    if (snapshot != null) {
```

---

**PROBLEM:**

That means anyone can access anyones's profile by constructing a url and pasting it in the searchbar and including the UID of that user.

---

**QUESTION:**

How can I check that the user is authenticated on the server without having such security breaches ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a authentication token instead of the uid, After the authentication process you will get the uid from Firebase and not from the user.

**Verify ID tokens using the Firebase Admin SDKs**

Web

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

Server (NodeJs)

```
// idToken comes from the client app (shown above)

admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {
    var uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // here you can use the uid of the user without the fear of Forgery 
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
```

Source:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Answer (score 1):

You could define an "authentication" middleware and mount it on any route you want to authorize:

```
var authenticate = function(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.cookies.token;

  if ( token ) {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .verifyIdToken(token)
      .then(function(decodedToken) {
        var uid = decodedToken.sub;
        if ( uid === req.params.uid ) {
          next()
        } else {
          console.log('This page is personal');
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        res.redirect('/login');
      });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
};
```

and use it like the following:

```
router.get("/profile/:uid", authenticate, function(req, res, next){

var uid = req.params.uid;

var userRef = admin.database().ref("users/"+uid);

userRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
    if (snapshot != null) {
```

Comment: Wouldn't using cookies be better ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243578/how-to-show-different-page-if-user-is-logged-in-via-firebase

Comment: Use any authentication technique you prefer. i just want to show you the big picture: using authentication middleware. It's just a matter of security. sessions are more secure than cookies. because in session authentication you maintain cookies on your server and don't send them back and force to clients.

Comment: ok, but I don't see how I would use your authentication middleware. Could you please explain a bit more ? Also I don't see how it prevents someone from accessing someone's else profile.

Comment: Use case is in the second code piece. If the token does not exist whithin your cookie or firebase auth can't verify it, it never calls **next()** and instead redirect them to **login** route.

Comment: Doesn't prevent anyone from logging in and then using a url like /users/profile/UIDofotheruser to access their profile, or is this incorrect ?

Comment: This allows any authenticated user to view any other users profile page. If you don't want to allow this you should check for that in the middleware. i updated the answer.