# Why is req.cookies undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, firebase, firebase-authentication

**SITUATION:**

I am trying to check if my user is authenticated when he makes a request to the server.

I googled a bit and found this:

[How to show different page if user is logged in via firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243578/how-to-show-different-page-if-user-is-logged-in-via-firebase)

So here's my try at implementing this solution using this library:

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/latest/src/js.cookie.js

---

**CODE:**

server-side

```
  var cookies = require("cookie-parser");

  router.get("/", function(req, res, next){


      const { token } = req.cookies;

      console.log('Verifying token', token);


 });
```

client-side

```
<script src="/public/js/cookieScript.js"> </script>

<a href="/upload" class = "authIn uploadButton btn btn-success pull-right">UPLOAD</a>

<script>

        const setAppCookie = () => firebase.auth().currentUser &&
            firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken().then(token => {
                Cookies.set('token', token, {
                    domain: window.location.hostname,
                    expire: 1 / 24, // One hour
                    path: '/',
                    secure: true // If served over HTTPS
             });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console ? You seem to have some code in <script> tags and some outside. I guess it's juste a different place where you pasted from... also, is the cookie properly set in your browser ?

Comment: @Pandaiolo Thx for coming to help ! Yes, the missing script tag for just a copy paste issue. How can I check if the cookie is properly set in my browser ?

Comment: @Pandaiolo Added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: @Pandaiolo Please add an answer so I can award you the bounty. I don't want to waste it. You put me in the right direction to find the answer.

Comment: I did, thanks @Coder1000 !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, your code is correct on the server. Hence, the cookie must not be set correctly on the client.

Copy/pasting the solution you found about disabling the secure cookie as you not using SSL:

```
    const setAppCookie = () => firebase.auth().currentUser &&
                firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken().then(token => {
                    Cookies.set('token', token, {
                        domain: window.location.hostname,
                        expire: 1 / 24, // One hour
                        path: '/',
                        secure: false // <-- false here when served over HTTP
                 });
            });
```

Answer (score 27):

In addition to requiring *cookie-parser* you should also configure your express app to use it:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cookies = require("cookie-parser");

app.use(cookies());
```

Comment: Thanks literally forgot to import cookie parser

Answer (score 17):

I think you should paste some more server side code.

You need to use express.cookieParser() before app.router; middleware is run in order, meaning it's never even reaching cookieParser() before your route is executed.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue !

My cookie is not served over https (yet).

```
 const setAppCookie = () => firebase.auth().currentUser &&
            firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken().then(token => {
                Cookies.set('token', token, {
                    domain: window.location.hostname,
                    expire: 1 / 24, // One hour
                    path: '/',
                    secure: true // If served over HTTPS
             });
        });
```

`secure` needed to be set to `false`.

Comment: I've worked on this issue for two days. Thanks for the question and the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable cookie-parser middleware ? 
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding credentials: 'include' to your fetch call, like so:

```
fetch(`${process.env.SERVER_URL}/`, { 
method: "POST",
credentials: "include",
headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
 })
 .then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
```

The reason it works when you manually access the address is because HTTP requests made by the browser send cookies in the header by default. Fetch doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

I am also stuck in this problem, there is a simple way to solve this problem, and that is to install cookie-parser, and then:

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const cookie Parser  = require("cookie-parser")
app.use(cookie Parser ())
```

That will solve it. If you find the same error reoccurs, just wait for an hour, shutdown your pc or laptop, then after some time when you try to get cookies in backend from frontend it's possible.

Note: Don't try again and again due this error are also occur.